# Oracle SQL. Select all hours in a day for every day of the year

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a query that returns the following result set (truncated for readability):

```
+---------------+-----------+--------+--------+----------+
| DATE_HAPPENED | Twelve_AM | One_AM | Two_AM | Three_AM | (and so on, until 24 hours)
+---------------+-----------+--------+--------+----------+
|  2015-10-01   |   110     |   34   |   92   |    45    |
+---------------+-----------+--------+--------+----------+
```

This is the code I'm using (and I'm not sure it's the best way to do it):

```
SELECT to_char(potty_use_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH12') as date_happened,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(potty_use_date, 'HH12 AM') = '12' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Twelve_AM,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(potty_use_date, 'HH12 AM') = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as One_AM,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(potty_use_date, 'HH12 AM') = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Two_AM,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(potty_use_date, 'HH12 AM') = '3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Three_AM,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(potty_use_date, 'HH12 AM') = '4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Four_AM,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(potty_use_date, 'HH12 AM') = '5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Five_AM,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(potty_use_date, 'HH12 AM') = '6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Six_AM,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(potty_use_date, 'HH12 AM') = '7' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Seven_AM,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(potty_use_date, 'HH12 AM') = '8' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Eight_AM,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(potty_use_date, 'HH12 AM') = '9' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Nine_AM,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(potty_use_date, 'HH12 AM') = '10' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Ten_AM,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(potty_use_date, 'HH12 AM') = '11' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Eleven_AM,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(potty_use_date, 'HH12 PM') = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as One_PM,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(potty_use_date, 'HH12 PM') = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Two_PM,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(potty_use_date, 'HH12 PM') = '3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Three_PM,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(potty_use_date, 'HH12 PM') = '4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Four_PM,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(potty_use_date, 'HH12 PM') = '5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Five_PM,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(potty_use_date, 'HH12 PM') = '6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Six_PM,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(potty_use_date, 'HH12 PM') = '7' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Seven_PM,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(potty_use_date, 'HH12 PM') = '8' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Eight_PM,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(potty_use_date, 'HH12 PM') = '9' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Nine_PM,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(potty_use_date, 'HH12 PM') = '10' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Ten_PM,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(potty_use_date, 'HH12 PM') = '11' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Eleven_PM,
    CASE WHEN to_char(potty_use_date, 'HH12 PM') = '12' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Twelve_PM
FROM core.potty_usage_statistics
GROUP BY to_char(potty_use_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH12')
ORDER BY date_happened ASC;
```

However, I'm getting the following results:

```
2015-04-20 08   1197    1197    1197    1197    1197    1197    1197    1197    1197    1197    1197    1197    1197    1197    1197    1197    1197    1197    1197    1197    1197    1197    1197    1197
```

They're all duplicated across the results window. Obviously, I am not doing this right. How do I do it right?

Comment: If you want to remove a value from the aggregation you need to return NULL in place of 0. Change your CASE/WHEN statement. COUNT(0) is the same of COUNT(1)...

Comment: What do you see when you give, for example, this query?  `SELECT potty_use_date, to_char(potty_use_date, 'HH12 AM') FROM core.potty_usage_statistics`  I suspect you're getting something besides a simple integer,

Comment: That's a lot of potty usage on a single day. :s

Comment: Oh wow. It returns as "10 AM", and so forth. /facepalm. Looks like I need to update that. @GolezTrol, I know, right?

Comment: I should also mention that 1 AM returns as 01 AM. Just found that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COUNT()` counts the number of non-`NULL` values.  If the values are 0 or 1, then all are non-`NULL`.  So, the count is the same as `COUNT(*)`.

Two options:

- Change the `COUNT()` to `SUM()`
- Remove the `ELSE 0`

Personally, I prefer the first method; but either is viable.

I should also note that you can use `EXTRACT()` for this purpose:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN extract(hour from potty_use_date) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Midnight,
```

Some might find this easier to read.

I also suspect that you want the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` to be:

```
SELECT to_char(potty_use_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as date_happened
. . .
GROUP BY to_char(potty_use_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

If you include the hour component, then you will get a diagonal of values, 24 rows for each day, with one hour column populated for each.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I would've figured out that last part eventually, but it's good to knock this off before going home for the weekend. This is an almost perfect explanation. Could you also explain the `EXTRACT()` usage a little more?

Comment: Your `extract()` suggestion gives me this error: `ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source`

Comment: @EduardoScissaro . . . `extract()` just extracts a date/time component from a date/time value.  It is ANSI standard, so it is available in more databases than `to_char()`.

Comment: @EduardoScissaro . . . I never noticed that before.  `extract()` only extracts year/month/day from a `date`.  It works on a `timestamp` for hour/minute/second.  Weird limitation, given that `date` stores a time component.

Comment: That's good to know. Glad we both learned something. Thanks a lot for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can pivot:

```
select * from 
(
  select
    trunc(p.potty_use_date) as potty_use_date,
    to_char(p.potty_use_date, 'HH24') as putty_use_hour,
  from
    core.potty_usage_statistics p
) 
pivot (
  count(putty_use_hour)
  for putty_use_hour in (
         '00' as "Midnight", '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', 
         '12' as "Noon", '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18' as "Dinner time", '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24' as "Or is this midnight")
)
```

I don't have Oracle at hand, so I couldn't test it, but this should work.

For more information about pivoting in Oracle, and an explanation why you need that entire list of hours, please read [SQL Operations: Pivot and Unpivot](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html)